# Ad Provider integration with PhoneGap App

Tags: windows-phone-7, cordova

How do I integrate ad providers with a PhoneGap App (for windows phone)?

Comment: WHat hae you tried? Are you looking to use native ad controls or html/js based ones?

Comment: @MattLacey I am looking for html/js based ones, I was able to find something like that from [inmobi](http://www.inmobi.com/). However, if there is a way to use native ad control with PhoneGap that would be great too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would think there are a couple of answers to this. One is to edit the XAML page, add the normal silverlight control to the page. This would require you to fiddle with the provided xaml from phonegap. This would give you access to the MS Ad Control and Google's Ad control for .net. At the end of the day, PhoneGap is just a silverlight page, with a browser control in it. So you can still edit that page, but you have to make sure you don't screw up the PhoneGap libraries and page.

The other solution is to find an html based ad control. Although this might not be possible with your ad provider.

Comment: I did edit the XAML and added AdMob as given [here](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/wp7/fundamentals) but when I run it on the emulator I get the following message: Error - Ad Not Available (NoFill)

Comment: That just means there were no ads ready (this happens) or your key or config isn't set up. Technically I think you're set, you have to fiddle with the ad control to make sure it serves up ads. This is a common issue with ad providers, sometimes you just don't get an ad. People use multiple controls to deal with this. If AdMob fails to provide an ad, default to AdControl. That just sounds complicated though.